# Scikit-learn: why does KernelDensity.score() provide a different result than GaussianMixture.score()?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, kernel-density

Comparing a parametric statistical modelling method (gaussian mixture modelling - GMM) with a nonparametric statistical modelling method (kernel density estimation - KDE), I wanted to use the Akaike Information Criteria (AIC) to take into account the parametric components that are used in gaussian mixture modelling.

Scikit-learn GaussianMixture class contains a .aic(X) method that returns the AIC directly. The KernelDensity class does not contain this method. In programming the algorithm I noticed that the GaussianMixture.score(X) method works different for both classes.

**[GaussianMixture.score(X) returns](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/ef5cb84a/sklearn/mixture/base.py#L308):**

log_likelihood : float

Log likelihood of the Gaussian mixture given X.

**[KernelDensity.score(X) returns:](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/ef5cb84a/sklearn/neighbors/kde.py#L161)**

logprob : float

Total log-likelihood of the data in X.

While not directly a problem for my code I was wondering if this was done on purpose, and if so, what that purpose would be. It did lead to initial misleading results before I found the difference, which is why I am putting this up on stackoverflow, in case other people found the same issue.